# Angular - Update data object in parent component which constantly changes due to Reactive Forms in child components

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am facing the following issue in Angular.
I have the parent component which operates a large JSON.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

myDataObservable$: Observable<MyObject>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myDataObservable$ = this.myService.fetchMyData();
}
```

and the template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myDataObservable$ | async as myData; else loading">
  <app-child-component [address]="myData.addressInfo" (addressChange)="myData.addressInfo = $event"></app-child-component>
....
```

And here is my Child Component which includes a Form Group which helps save the data which gets added / changed by the customer:

```
export class MyChildComponent implements OnInit {

formData: FormGroup;
@ViewChild('userForm') userForm: NgForm;

@Input() address: IAddressData;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formData = this.formBuilder.group({
        street: [this.address.streetInfo.street.value],
        hausNumber: [this.address.streetInfo.hausNumber.value],
        city: [this.address.city.value],
        country: [this.address.country.value],
    });

    this.formData.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.addressChange.emit(this.updateData(this.formData.value))
    })
}
```

The problem is that my object IAddressData contains more fields than my form, furthermore the field names does not match and hence my parent component does not get a proper object only when I update the values one by one....

```
private updateData(data: any): IAddressData {
    let rp = this.address;
    rp.streetInfo.street.value = data.street;
    rp.agrarDieselInfo.agrarDiesel.wert = data.hausNumber
    rp.city.value = data.city;
    rp.country.value = data.country;
    return rp;
}
```

Is there any other easier way to achieve this besides this extra function of mapping the fields from my form to the parent object?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the mapping, you can create a FormGroup with the structure of your object:

```
new FormGroup({
  streetInfo: new FormGroup({
    street: new FormControl(),
    hausNumber: new FormControl(),
  }),
  city: new FormControl(),
  country: new FormControl(),
})

formGroup.patchValue(initialValueFromTheInput);
```

Then to set the value you can use `patchValue`, which will do the mapping even if the object you pass has more fields. And to get the updated object you could merge your initial object with what you get from `getRawValue`, e.g. with the merge function from lodash.